# File sharing between a windows 8 Virtual machine and a windows 7 host machine in VMware workstation

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, virtual-machine, file-sharing, vmware-workstation

I have files and portable applications on windows 7 Host Machine. How can I access this from windows 8 Virtual machine which is on VMware workstation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure works with Windows 8 or any other Windows actually, it's not Windows 8 exclusive:

1. Once installed the operating system in the virtual machine install VMware Tools (with the VM running click on the `VM` menu and select to install VMware Tools). It'll mount an image in one of your CD/DVD drivers.
2. Start the installation program within the virtual machine:

   [image: Starting the installation program]
3. Once installed you'll be prompted to reboot the machine, do so.
4. After the reboot you'll see that there's a new icon by the clock in the classic desktop, it denotes that VMware Tools (they enhance the performance of the virtual machine's guest operating system and improve its management).

After that you'll be able to transfer files and folder from and to the VM's operating system by drag and drop for example.

---

A more permanent way is to setup shared folders between both machines. In the `Options` tab of the virtual machine settings dialog you can setup folder mappings between both OSs, and even specify if they're to be read only:

[image: Shared folder options]

Since the guest OS is Windows selecting to map them as network drivers will make them appear in `Computer` just like any other:

[image: Access to mapped folders]

If you don't wish to map them as a network drive you can access your shared folders over network:

```
\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\shared_folder_name
```

[image: Access shared folders via network]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from Settings, Just follow the steps,

- Go to Edit > Virtual Machine Settings > Options and click Shared folders.

Look at the image for more information,

[image]

After setting shared folder, you need start your virtual operating system.